# Get TOP5 but from various groups

Tags: mysql, group-by

Simple task. I have blogging system and I need to get TOP5 (by views) posts, but from various authors (e.g. if one author is very popular I don't need all five posts from them only).

It can be done easily, if choosing TOP5 authors first and then choosing the most popular post from each. But the question is: could it be done in a single query?

Comment: Those aren't the same logically. A post from an author with lots of semi-popular posts would get selected over a post from an author who posted one mega popular post.

Comment: Please update your question with (at minimum) some sample data and the desired result. As is, it's hard to understand what you're asking (especially since you haven't tried anything)

Comment: What is a popular author? One with many posts? One with many views on their posts?

Comment: @AndriyM They want the top 5 popular **posts** (not authors), that are posted by different authors. So it could be the 1st, 2nd, 5th, 6th, 9th top posts  (if 3rd, 4th, 7th and 9th have same authors as the others.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer to the question:  "Could it be done in a single query?" is "Yes".  I just can't figure out what "it" is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an auto_increment id:

```
  SELECT p1.* 
    FROM posts p1
    JOIN (
       SELECT p2.author, p2.views, MAX(p2.id) author_max_id
         FROM posts p2
         JOIN (
         SELECT p3.author, MAX(p3.views) author_max_views
           FROM posts p3
       GROUP BY p3.author
       ORDER BY author_max_views
          LIMIT 5 
              ) pii
           ON p2.author = pii.author
          AND p2.views = pii.author_max_views
     GROUP BY p2.author, p2.views
     ORDER BY p2.views
        LIMIT 5
         ) pi
      ON p1.author = pi.author
     AND p1.views = pi.views
     AND p1.id = pi.author_max_id
ORDER BY p1.views
   LIMIT 5;
```

I had to double nest to avoid the case where an author has more than one post with views = maximum views for that author.

This may be rewritable to something simpler... for example, you don't need the `ORDER BY x LIMIT 5` in the two sub queries, but I am hoping they will speed up the query.

Comment: Always was a little upset, that SQL-language requires so much effort to accomplish such a simple task...

Comment: @DenisKulagin It's great for most tasks that fall within a certain mindset, but this is quite a niche selection.